# Enviar datos a sql segun radiobutton selecionado mvc5

Tags: javascript, sql, html5, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo el siguiente problema,  tengo un formulario en mvc5 lleno todos los datos, pero quiero que uno de los datos se inserte en la base de datos según lo seleccionado, por un Radiobuttom, ese imput se llama TotalBilledAmount  y tengo en la base de datos varias columnas entre ellas dos que se llaman  billedAmountServices  y BilledAmountGoods, quiero que según el radiobuttom seleccionado la data de totalbilledAmount se repliquen una de las dos columnas. Quiero destacar que no tengo experiencia haciendo esto y espero que la explicación sea muy explicita  gracias de antemano

Este es mi controlador,

```html
  public async Task<ActionResult> Create(GoodsAndServicePurchase goodsAndServicePurchase)
        {

          
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    db.GoodsAndServicePurchases.Add(goodsAndServicePurchase);
                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

              
        }
```

Este es mi vista

```html
 <div class="form-group"><label>Monto Facturado <span class="label-required">(*)</span></label><input type="text" name="TotalBilledAmount"  id="TotalBilledAmount" placeholder="Monto Facturado RD$" class="form-control" required data-error=""></div>
 
 
  <input id="rc1" checked type="radio" name="rc1">Servicio<br>
                        <input id="rc2" type="radio" name="rc1">Bienes<br>
```

Comment: Bienvenido Bryant, te recomiendo 3 cosas: 1. Ver el recorrido https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla en el sitio. 2. Ver cómo preguntar en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 3. Revisar este workshop que hice sobre ASP.net MVC 5: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY :D